# Vector that can be expressed as a convex linear combination

Tags: vectors, convex-analysis

I'm having some trouble with a (seemingly easy) math problem:

Given are the vectors $a_1=(4,2), a_2=(1,4), a_3=(3,0)$ and $a_4=(3,2)$.
Show that vector $a_4$ can be expressed as a convex linear combination of vectors $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$.

So far I've tried:
$1. 4x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 = 3$

$2. 2x_1 + 4x_2  = 2$

Then for $2$.

$x_1 = 2-2x_2$

I tried inserting $x_1$ into the first element but somehow, I end up with weird numbers.

The solution should be:
$a_4= 0a_1 + 0.25a_2 + 0.25a_3$

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE! Please use MathJaX to typeset formulas and other mathematical content. See here for examples math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The solution cannot be $a_4= 0a_1 + 0.25a_2 + 0.25a_3$ because this is not a convex linear combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider that there exists some $a,b,c\in K$, where $K$ is your field such as
$$a_4=a\cdot a_1+b\cdot a_2+c\cdot a_3$$
That's possible since these three vectors are a generating system of the vectorial space. Now
$$(3,2)=a(4,2)+b(1,4)+c(3,0)$$
So we end up with the system
$$3=4a+b+3c\\ 2=2a+4b$$
Since we want a convex combination we add a new equation:
$$3=4a+b+3c\\ 2=2a+4b\\a+b+c=1$$
Which solution is $a=1/2, b=1/4, c=1/4$